# Can Athena data sources be configured via Cloudormation or CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, amazon-athena

I need to configure Athena to connect to a couple of data sources - MySQL RDS, Postgres RDS, and a custom federation Lambda.

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to configure these via Cloudformation so I can commit these configurations. I cannot seem seem find any resources to configure these data sources - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_Athena.html

The AWS CLI doesn't seem to support the creation of data sources as well. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/

Are there APIs or other ways to configure Athena data sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic you're looking for is the [`AWS::Athena::DataCatalog`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-athena-datacatalog.html#cfn-athena-datacatalog-type) resource. You can use that to create a new data catalog that points to your federated data source by providing a `Type` value of `LAMBDA`. Here's a sample JSON template for creating a new federated data source:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  Type: 'AWS::Athena::DataCatalog'
  Properties:
    Name: mysql
    Type: LAMBDA
    Description: Awesome MySQL Database
    Parameters:
      function: 'arn:aws:lambda:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT_ID>:function:lambdaname'
```

Or the CLI

```bash
aws athena create-data-catalog \
  --name excel_files \
  --type LAMBDA \
  --parameters function=arn:aws:lambda:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT_ID>:function:athena-excel
```

The provided function is the ARN of the Lambda function for your data source, which also needs to get deployed.

For the officially supported data sources in [aws-athena-query-federation repo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-athena-query-federation), they are available in the [Serverless Application Repository](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications) (SAR) and can also be deployed using the [AWS SAM CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/install-sam-cli.html) as they all typically have various additional roles and configuration required to run.

If you want to use CloudFormation, you can grab the SAR Application ARN and parameters. These can be found either when you're creating the data source or by searching the SAR. For MySql the ARN is `arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:292517598671:applications/AthenaMySQLConnector` so the CloudFormation template would look something like this (plus all the additional parameters):

```yaml
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Resources:
  AthenaMySQLConnector:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Application'
    Properties:
      Location:
        ApplicationId: >-
          arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:292517598671:applications/AthenaMySQLConnector
        SemanticVersion: 2023.37.2
      Parameters:
        DefaultConnectionString: YOUR_VALUE
        LambdaFunctionName: mysqlconnector
        SecretNamePrefix: YOUR_VALUE
        SecurityGroupIds: YOUR_VALUE
        SpillBucket: YOUR_VALUE
        SubnetIds: YOUR_VALUE
```

So to sum up, create the Lambda then create the `DataCatalog` resource to point to the Lambda.